# version string has embedded spaces

Tags: release-juno

While upgrading elementary os, I get following error from appstream:

`dpkg: error: version '/usr/share/app-info/yaml /usr/share/app-info/icons' has bad syntax: version string has embedded spaces`

Everything looks normal, but is this something that I can fix easily? Thanks,

Full error is as belows:

```
  appstream-data-pantheon appstream-data-pantheon-icons appstream-data-pantheon-icons-hidpi
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 498 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 appstream-data-pantheon all 5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1 [197 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 appstream-data-pantheon-icons all 5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1 [205 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 appstream-data-pantheon-icons-hidpi all 5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1 [96.4 kB]
Fetched 498 kB in 1s (336 kB/s)                                
(Reading database ... 254963 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../appstream-data-pantheon_5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking appstream-data-pantheon (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) over (5.0-0+r79~daily~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../appstream-data-pantheon-icons_5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking appstream-data-pantheon-icons (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) over (5.0-0+r79~daily~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../appstream-data-pantheon-icons-hidpi_5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking appstream-data-pantheon-icons-hidpi (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) over (5.0-0+r79~daily~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
Setting up appstream-data-pantheon (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) ...
Setting up appstream-data-pantheon-icons (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) ...
Setting up appstream-data-pantheon-icons-hidpi (5.0-0+r82~ubuntu5.1.1) ...
Processing triggers for appstream (0.12.9-1+elementary10~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
dpkg: error: version '/usr/share/app-info/yaml /usr/share/app-info/icons' has bad syntax: version string has embedded spaces
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is very recent and affects many users and has been confirmed here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1848387

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really don't effect much but still annoying.